# Avoid automatically switching to other virtual desktop when opening a folder again

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Recently, I have been playing around with virtual desktops in Windows 10 and was surprised by the following behaviour:

I have a folder lying on my desktop. On virtual desktop 1, I open the folder (double click). Now I switch to virtual desktop 2 and open it again. I would expect a second file explorer to be opened, one on each virtual desktop. Instead, Windows automatically switches back to virtual desktop 1 and focuses the existing explorer.

Is this a bug or the intended behaviour? Is there a way to avoid it, e.g. some setting to make virtual desktops to be "more separate" than per default?

Comment: This is intended behavior. I haven't played much with it, but I believe it can be turned off. Given that I'm not sure about the turning off part and how, this is a comment, not an answer. I did read however that this is how virtual desktops work in windows 10. They want to make sure that people are not losing track of their windows.

Comment: Great question. This is very bad functionality when you want separate desktops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears this can be worked around by going to `File` -> `Change folder and search options` -> `View` and checking the option to `Launch folder windows in a separate process`.

This option has been in Windows a long time, and it comes with its own set of fairly subtle side effects (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Do you remember any of said side side effects? The only thing I found online is higher memory consumption (which is not an issue on my machine).

Comment: After playing with it a bit, I think the memory is probably the only issue. I believe (maybe in Windows XP) it would keep opening new Explorer instances when you would double click a folder *in Explorer*. This was quite annoying, but appears to not happen anymore or perhaps I'm thinking of another setting.

Comment: I don't know about Windows XP, but in Windows 10 that behaviour is governed by a dedicated setting in Folder Options / General / Browse Folders.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus, if you have that option turned off, you can still open a folder in a new process by holding `Shift` and left-clicking to get the context menu. `Open in new process` will become available.